# try catch does not catch exception?

Tags: php, exception

I have code like below

```
try {
  $user = $query->getSingleResult();
} catch (Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
  return null;
} catch (Exception $e) {
  return null;
}
```

`getSingleResult()` will throw `NoResultException` if no rows are found. and it seems I am still getting the exception ... the catch does not seem to work. why is that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If your code is namespaced, try using:

```
catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e)
```

Note the backslash in front of the Doctrine namespace.

The reason you need to do this is because PHP's namespaces are relative, instead of absolute.

If your code is namespaced to `My\Namespace`, and you try to catch `Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException`, in reality it tries to catch `My\Namespace\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException`.

By prefixing the namespace with a \ you make it absolute (similar to unix pathnames)

Comment: This is most likely because the user is using Doctrine 2 which _is_ namespaced.

Comment: Using Doctrine 2 does not force you to namespace your own code though. In a case where you haven't specified a namespace for your code, the namespace is always assumed to be at root, in which case you wouldn't need the initial \

Comment: You can as well just do a catch of `NoResultException` and add a `use Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException;` in your file header.

Answer (score 3):

Its also possible to add a

```
 use Exception;
```

On the top of the class and it will resolve the Exception class name used in the try/catch block.